# Using kinect to track a hand without a body image

Tags: kinect

I'm just learning to develop on Kinect. I know that its algorithm uses a probability distribution on individual pixels to decide on the body part in the region.

My question is, could I access a hand position without Kinect seeing the entire body? As in the case where the body is too close to the device or mostly hidden? I'm using KinectSDK from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is possible in MS Kinect SDK, but using the new "beta" OpenNI SDK you can track the users without them being fully in view/calibrating and get access to the hand points, also are there other vendors who give SDK for body tracking which you might want to try (OMEK is one).

Answer (score 1):

You can  - I'm using SimpleOpenNI with Processing, but the MS SDK should let you use a similar method.

First you have to enable hand tracking:

```
  kinect.enableGesture ();
  kinect.enableHands ();
  kinect.addGesture ("RaiseHand"); //Wave, Swipe, RaiseHand and Click
```

then use methods below - note that you don't have to use the convertRealWorldToProjective method if you're interested in 3D data.

```
  void onCreateHands(int HandId, PVector position, float time) {
    PVector convHand = new PVector ();
    thisHand = position;
    kinect.convertRealWorldToProjective(position, convHand);
    currHand = convHand;
  }

  void onUpdateHands(int HandId, PVector position, float time) {
    PVector convHand = new PVector ();
    thisHand = position;
    kinect.convertRealWorldToProjective(position, convHand);
    currHand = convHand;
  }

  void onDestroyHands(int HandId, PVector position, float time) {
    PVector convHand = new PVector ();
    kinect.convertRealWorldToProjective(position, convHand);
    currHand = new PVector (0, 0, 0);
    }

  void onRecognizeGesture (String strGesture, PVector idPosition, PVector endPosition)       {
    kinect.startTrackingHands (endPosition);
    kinect.removeGesture ("RaiseHand");
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you still want it or not but you can try putting up your hand in front of the kinect making it the closest object to it. then access the depthmap and find the pixels closest to it while setting other pixels color value to black

Answer (score 0):

You can segment the pixels of a particular region of your body (for example hands, thighs, etc.) using the Depth frames from Kinect and compare their pixel location with the skeleton segments. A depth pixel can be assigned to a particular skeleton segment if its distance from it is the smallest compared to other skeleton segments. It is important that you compute the distance from line segments and not from joints (i.e. points).

This example shows real-time segmentation of torso, head, arms, forearms, thighs and legs:
[image]

You can read more technical details about how to implement it in this article about [Kinect Avatars](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/Kinect_Avatars.pdf).